# Replace a substring by another one in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openwrt

I have the following bash script

```
pass="kall"
cnumb="000000000000"

for (( i=0; i<${#pass}; i++))
do
    code=`printf '%03d' "'${pass:i:i+1}"` #generate the code ASCII of letter as string with 3 chars
    cnumb = .... #put the code ASCII of "k" in the first bloc of 3 chars , put the code ASCII of "a" in the second bloc of 3 chars, ...
done
```

As described in the code, I want to repace in each iteration in the loop a bloc of 3 chars in the cnumb by another bloc of 3 charachters. How to do it with bash

Is it possible to replace the sub string `${cnumb:i:i+3}` by the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put zeroes to cnumb. Also, use the `%03d` template for `printf`:

```
#! /bin/bash
pass="kall"
cnumb=''

for (( i=0; i<${#pass}; i++))
do
    code=`printf '%03d' "'${pass:i:i+1}"` #generate the code ASCII of letter as string with 3 chars
    cnumb+=$code
done
echo "$cnumb"
```

Comment: that's what I m looking for. Thank you